# Using specs2 + scalacheck to validate type classes (simple Arbitrary[...] example)

Tags: scala, validation, specs2, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I'm having trouble getting specs2 and scalacheck to cooperate. I have a simple class, `Credit`, that takes a single integer within the range of 1 to 59 (anything outside of this range should throw an exception).

I want to define two tests: 1 test that validates the positive cases (any `Credit(1)` ... `Credit(59)` validates successfully); and, any `Credit` outside of that range should fail to validate (it should actually throw an exception when constructed). It seems like the right approach is to define an `Arbitrary[Credit]` generator, like so:

```
implicit lazy val arbitraryCreditGenerator: Arbitrary[Credit] = Arbitrary(creditGenerator)
```

And then I would define an `arbitraryBadCreditGenerator` too.

The problem is the implicit use of the arbitrary, and trying to figure out the syntax for using `prop` with my two different arbitrary instances.

What I have so far is:

```
case class Credit(amount: Int)

object Credit {
    implicit val creditValidator = validator[Credit] { c =>
        c.amount should be > 0
        c.amount should be < 60
    }
} 

class TestCreditModel extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is = s2"""
   Given a credit
   When validation is performed
   Then credits between 1 and 60 should be acceptable ${creditsAreValid}
   And credits less than 1 or greater than 60 should not ${creditsAreInvalid}
   """

   implicit lazy val arbitraryCreditGenerator: Arbitrary[Credit] = Arbitrary(creditGenerator)

   val creditGenerator = Gen.choose(1,59).map(Credit(_))
   val badCreditGenerator = (Gen.choose(-500, 500) suchThat (n => n < 1 || n > 59)).map(Credit(_))

   def creditsAreValid = prop { (a: Credit) => validate(a).isSuccess must beTrue }

   // Err... oops... how do I use my badCreditGenerator???
   def creditsAreInvalid = prop { (a: badCreditGenerator) => validate(a).isSuccess must beFalse }
   //                              ^ compile error... not defined

}
```

I'm using Accord for validation, so any attempt to create a `Credit` with invalid range should fail.

This does not compile, because my use `badCreditGenerator` is all wrong. I've been fiddling with it and trying to come up with the solution; ideally I'd have two arbitrary generators, one that generates "good" `Credit` instances and one that tries to generate bad ones.

Maybe there's a better way?

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'll write a longer answer later but you can write `prop { (a: Credit) => ...}.setGen(myGenerator)` to pass in a specific generator. If there are several parameters for your property you want to set you can write `setGens` with all of them or just `setGen1`, `setGen2`... to set one of them.

Comment: Is there a particular value in using an implicit along with `setGen()` or does it make more sense to simply toss the implicit and go with a `forAll`, which seems to be giving me what I need (and is simpler; no need to define an implicit arbitrary). So right now I'm using `def creditsAreInvalid = forAll(badCreditGenerator) { (c: Credit) => validate(c).isSuccess must beFalse }`.

Comment: `forAll` works as well. I personally like the `setGen` variations because less rewriting is involved when adding/removing parameters. Also I generally only define one implicit `Arbitrary` for "ok/default" values and use generators for other cases.